# Help Building Custom BAXTER grippers

Tags: ros, gazebo, gripper, baxter, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need help figuring out these two errors. They are both related, so solving one should solve the other.
I'm building custom grippers for Baxter in Ros-Indigo (ubuntu 1404.2). I've built a custom URDF file along with a custom launch file. This error is the last error I have to figure out.

```
 [baxter_sim_kinematics_left-6] process has died [pid 27862, exit code -11, cmd /home/veyorokon/ros/baxter_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_kinematics/kinematics left __name:=baxter_sim_kinematics_left __log:=/home/veyorokon/.ros/log/9cdf8088-940e-11e5-9ec4-b8e85645ebf8/baxter_sim_kinematics_left-6.log].
log file: /home/veyorokon/.ros/log/9cdf8088-940e-11e5-9ec4-b8e85645ebf8/baxter_sim_kinematics_left-6*.log
[baxter_sim_kinematics_right-7] process has died [pid 27921, exit code -11, cmd /home/veyorokon/ros/baxter_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_kinematics/kinematics right __name:=baxter_sim_kinematics_right __log:=/home/veyorokon/.ros/log/9cdf8088-940e-11e5-9ec4-b8e85645ebf8/baxter_sim_kinematics_right-7.log].
log file: /home/veyorokon/.ros/log/9cdf8088-940e-11e5-9ec4-b8e85645ebf8/baxter_sim_kinematics_right-7*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221554/help-building-custom-baxter-grippers/) by [veyorokon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25149/veyorokon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update:** I have reworked some of the logic in Baxter's simulated Position Kinematics node to prevent it from making the  assumption that I mention below. You can now have additional joints on your Baxter URDF without any naming restrictions. The fix can be viewed here: https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter_simulator/pull/73

**Original Answer:** The `baxter_sim_kinematics` node makes a very bad assumption - all of the joints for the arm will be the only ones that begin with the strings `<left/right>`, rather than loading all 7 of them from a param or yaml file. Then whenever an additional joint is added that starts with `<left/right>`, it core dumps. Not a great design. It is a bit far down on my bug list to tackle, as it requires someone be adding a custom end effector to Baxter. As a workaround, start your joint with `<l/r>` or any other string that is not "left" or "right" instead. Please open a ticket for this on `baxter_simulator` if there isn't one already. Sorry for the inconvenience!

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [veyorokon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25149/veyorokon/) on 2015-11-27**:
Thanks that worked! Just for clarification, I went into my URDF file and adjusted all the joint names that started with:
"right_..." or "left_..."
to
"r_..." and "l_..." respectively. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Exit code `-11` is a segmentation fault. I suggest you run your node in a debugger.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1